# Добавление контакта по номеру телефона Python Pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

Пробовал так:

```
client.import_contacts([InputPhoneContact(phone=f"+{contact}", first_name=temp_contact_name)])
```

И так:

```
client.add_contact(contact, first_name=temp_contact_name)
```

Нужно добавление контакта так чтобы как будто вручную, то есть добавить можно было человека которому ты не писал и ранее не добавлял